# Javascript: How to re-arrange content display of text field?

Tags: javascript

I have a text field (not a date field) who contain simply a value such "2013-08-27" and my goal would be to reverse the order and get "27-08-2013". So is matter to re-arrange the content but I don't have enough javascript knowledge. I tried using some "date" variable but without success much probably because my field is not a date field.

The html related to the field look like this:

```
<input type="text" value="2013-08-27" name="my_field" id="my-field" readonly="">
```

If you can give me an example of code based of this:

```
var my_field = document.getElementById('my_field');
```

thank

PS: I precise I don't have access to html of this field because is located to a remote server. I can only interact by adding code in a JS file planned for that. The field have also a "readonly" property because is not planned for be modified.

Comment: What, other than just selecting the field, have you done? I'm sure if you make a little effort you can find how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should do the trick:

```
var revert = function(str) {
    var parts = str.split("-");
    var newArr = [];
    for(var i=parts.length-1; p=parts[i]; i--) {
       newArr.push(p);
    }
    return newArr.join("-");
}
var replaceValueInInputField = function(id) {
    var field = document.getElementById(id);
    field.value = revert(field.value);
}
var replaceValueInDomNode = function(id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    var value = el.innerHTML, newValue = '';
    var matches = value.match(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})\-(\d{2})/g);
    for(var i=0; m=matches[i]; i++) {
        value = value.replace(m, revert(m));
    }    
    el.innerHTML = value;
}

replaceValueInInputField("my-field");
replaceValueInDomNode("my-field2");
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qtDjF/2/

Comment: You rock your code work well :-). However I just noticed in another area, the value remain like before. The code look like this: <li id="my-field2">
<b>Label of My field</b>
2013-08-27
</li>. Do you think is possible to interact also here ?

Comment: It's done. I edited the jsfiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/qtDjF/2/
The idea is to use regex to match the date and then use the same approach.

Comment: I tested but unfortunately this don't work. I lost also the previous trick who worked fine before :-(. Have you another suggestion ?

Comment: I should see what you did. I mean if you look at my jsfiddle you will see how I implemented the new code. You should call a function. It doesn't happen automatically.

Comment: The problem is the second value present in "my-field2" is located to another page where I can't interact with JS. Not your fault..I will see if I can do something but I doubt.

Comment: Ah ... then I guess that you can't apply the same js solution.

Comment: Yes, the only solution seem to ask to developer of the remote software to extend JS capability in the other area. In any case many thank for your help and time.

Answer (score 2):

`split('-')` will return an array of number strings
`reverse()`  will order array backwards
`join("-")`  will join array back with '-' symbol

```
var my_field_value = document.getElementById('my_field').value;
my_field_value.split('-').reverse().join("-");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the split function.

```
var my_field = document.getElementById('my_field').split("-");
```

the var my_field will be an array of string like : "YYYY,mm,dd"
and then you can re-arrange it in the order you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var date =  document.getElementById("my-field").value;
//alert(date);
var sp = date.split("-");
alert(sp[2]+"-"+sp[1]+"-"+sp[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

With Jquery

```
var parts =$('#my-field').val().split("-");
$('#my-field').val(parts[2]+"-"+parts[1]+"-"+parts[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple regex:

```
var res;
test.replace(/(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)/,function(all,a,b,c){res=c+"-"+b+"-"+a;});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dzdA7/8/

Answer (score 0):

You could try splitting the string into array and inverting it's items in a loop:

```
var my_field = document.getElementById('my_field').value.split("-"),
    length = my_field.length,
    date = [];

for(i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    date.push(my_field[i]);
}

console.log(date.toString().replace(/,/g,"-"));
```